# ruby if string contains

Tags: ruby

With the following code, I expect `Bravo` if the file name is `123456.txt`.

```
if File_Name#=~ ('.+(775|776|777|778)\.txt')
  @outputs['answer'] = 'Alpha'
elsif File_Name#=~ (.+(456|546)\.txt)
  @outputs['answer'] = 'Bravo'
```

But the answer results in `Alpha`. What am I missing here?

Comment: What is `File_Name`? What is `@outputs`? How is the file name that you are mentioning involved in the code? Your code is invalid without `end`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#` defines the start of a comment. The operator to test against regexes is `=~`, not `#=~`.

```
if File_Name
```

will be the case being picked, unless `File_Name` is `false` or `nil`, hence why you always get `'Alpha'`.

---

Also the literal syntax to create regexes is `//`, not `('')`:

```
if File_Name =~ /.+(775|776|777|778)\.txt/
```

Comment: Thanks, got a little closer.  Now its stuck on Bravo, the list goes on for about 10 answer fields.  Sorry I cannot seem to figure out how to put these into code breaks.  

  if ['File_Name'] =~ ('.+(775|776|777|778)\.txt')
  @outputs['answer'] = 'Alpha'
elsif ['File_Name'] =~ (.+(456|546)\.txt)
  @outputs['answer'] = 'Bravo'

Comment: Tried the update. but still stuck on Bravo answer even when using 456775.txt that should report Alpha

Comment: @user3500099, you are doing something else wrong. Here is a quick example to verify that it works: `puts 'It works' if '456775.txt' =~ /.+(775|776|777|778)\.txt/`.

Comment: Sorry, put it as simple as I could and it does not work.    if '123775.txt' =~ /.+(775|776|777|778|779|780|781|782|783|784|785|786|501)\.txt/
    @outputs['answer'] = 'Alpha'     returns nil.

Comment: @user3500099, remove the `'`s inside the `//`.

Comment: ugh, its the smallest piece that will always break the system.  after this I was able to make the entire code to work as expected.  Thank you for your patience with me!